# Override PreSaveAction in Form

Tags: workflow, form

Is there a way to override a PreSaveAction if a certain condition is met?

I have a two-step custom approval workflow process where I am currently using the PreSaveAction to ensure that the "Reviewer 2" field is completed before saving. However, if Reviewer 1 selects reject, then Reviewer 2 does not need to be required.

Here is the PreSaveAction script that I currently have running.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction(){
    //these look for the display name values in the associated people pickers
    var rev2 = $("input[Title='Reviewer 2']").attr("aria-label");

    if(rev2){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("You must select a person as Reviewer 2. Please refer to the Approval and Payment of Invoices policy for guidelines.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `PreSaveItem` which doesn't override the submit button but is used more for validation, and won't save until the validation runs true.

See: http://blog.riccardocelesti.it/using-presaveitem-to-add-custom-validation-to-sharepoint-list-form/

Comment: Sorry, I have no Javascript knowledge. Someone gave me the script I am using. How does the PreSaveItem differ and what would I need to change?

Comment: PreSaveItem is just a call before the submit action, PreSaveAction overrides the submit button to do your own thing.